# How to make a proper HttpPost to fetch some data from a website?

Tags: android, json, http-post

I'm building an app that requires getting some JSON formatted data from a website, parsing and using it.

I managed to get it working on my home machine (WAMP), but am unable to do the same with the actual website.

The website is `www.ace.ucv.ro/android/android.php`.

This is what I do:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ace.ucv.ro/android/android.php");
```

And it doesn't return anything. Please help me out and tell me what I need to put in there... Is it the server IP or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a valid example on how to use `HttpGet` :

```
String url = "http://www.ace.ucv.ro/android/android.php";

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet).getEntity());

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
```

I usually would make it even more compact into something like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(url)).getEntity()));
```

Make sure to declare the correct permission for internet access in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer my noob problems! Is there anyway I can test if this works? Output it somehow? (Yes, I am a big noob and this is a bit out of my league, but I'm learning...:D)

Comment: LE: It still doesn't output anything. The ServerResponse String is still empty.

Comment: THANK YOU! So much! Millions of thanks! Sorry for asking questions obvious for experienced coders but I really had a hard time finding info and resources on this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh-oh...I thought it works because it returns the "serverResponse" String accurately. However it doesn't create the JSONObject...no matter what I do...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to *Get* data, try `HttpGet`.

Comment: Thanks! I followed a tutorial to do this and I didn't find many resources about this.